# Eager loading of rails lib

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

It looks like this issue will be solved in Rails 4:
http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2012/08/eager-loading-for-greater-good/
but until then, I'm wondering how to eager-load modules/classes in my `/lib`.

In IRB it appears that they are loaded on-demand the first time I try to access:

```
Foo::Bar.constants
=> []

Foo::Bar::Service
=> Foo::Bar::Service

Foo::Bar.constants
=> [:ServiceBase, :Service]
```

I have several other classes in that module, and my code depends on being able to look them up using `Foo::Bar.const_defined?` at runtime - how do I ensure all `Foo::Bar`'s classes get loaded at startup?

I'm already using `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)` in `application.rb`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Putting this in `root/config/initializers/eager.rb` should load all .rb files in that folder:

```
Dir["#{Rails.root}/lib/*.rb"].each {|file| load file}
```

Comment: Doesn't `load` require a filename? I tried it several ways to load the entire dir but doesn't seem to work. `LoadError: cannot load such file -- foo`

Comment: @devth, please try revised answer.

Comment: just realized having that in an initializer loads them for the first request in development env, but subsequent requests don't eager load the classes. How do you eager load them for every request in development?

Comment: Dir[Rails.root.join("lib/*.rb")] looks better :)

Answer (score 6):

For me putting this in application.rb solved the problem

```
config.eager_load_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

Comment: This works for me. The code line includes all directories in lib-directory into eager_load_paths.

Answer (score 1):

Use `eager_load_paths` combined with `ActiveSupport::Reloader`'s `to_prepare` hook inside `development.rb`:

```
config.eager_load_paths += Dir["app/models/stimodel/**/*.rb"]  
ActiveSupport::Reloader.to_prepare do  
  Dir["app/models/stimodel/**/*.rb"].each { |f| require_dependency("#{Dir.pwd}/#{f}") }
end
```

Adding your paths to `eager_load_paths` make sure that Rails loads them when it starts up. To make sure that Rails reloads our models if we do any changes or add new files, we also need to hook into the Reloader's `to_prepare` hook and manually require the dependency there.